# How to calculate a route between 2 points using google maps directions API in my React app without displaying a map?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, directions, react-google-maps, google-directions-api

I'm trying to calculate a route between 2 points using google maps directions. When I tried the following code, I got an error:

Access to fetch at 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?destination=31.922007%2C34.768531&mode=driving&origin=32.087001%2C34.8226326&key=MY_KEY' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I saw here: [CORS request is not working on google directions API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42024771/cors-request-is-not-working-on-google-directions-api) that I cannot use the API this way but I can use the direction service https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions

```
import { createClient } from '@google/maps';
import { GOOGLE_GEOCODE_API_KEY } from '../config/keys';

let googleMapsClient;

function initialize() {
    googleMapsClient = createClient({key: GOOGLE_GEOCODE_API_KEY});
}

function getGoogleMapsClient() {
    if (!googleMapsClient) {
        initialize();
    }

    return googleMapsClient;
}

function calcRoute(origin, destination) {
    return getGoogleMapsClient().directions({
        origin: origin,
        destination: destination,
        mode: 'driving',
    });
}
```

As I understand from the documents of the directions service, I must present a map in my app to make the route calculation, but I don't want to. In addition, the documents are dedicated to JS and I'm working with react.
How can I make the calculation in react without displaying the map?

Answer (score 0):

The map instance is not a mandatory to utilize  [Google Maps Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions), it is is also supported to pass `<div>` element to render route information, from documentation:

> A `DirectionsRenderer` not only handles display of the polyline and any
>   associated markers, but also can handle the textual display of
>   directions as a series of steps. To do so, simply call setPanel() on
>   your `DirectionsRenderer`, passing it the  in which to display this
>   information.

Here is an example:

```
class RouteInfo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.directionsPanelRef = React.createRef();
    this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.directionsDisplay.setPanel(this.directionsPanelRef.current);
    this.displayRoute();
  }

  displayRoute() {
    this.request = {
      origin: "chicago, il",
      destination: "st louis, mo",
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    this.directionsService.route(this.request, (response, status) => {
      if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        this.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        console.log("Directions request failed due to " + status);
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div ref={this.directionsPanelRef} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/yy33lq699)