# Basic usage of Google Maps Directions API in client-side JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-directions-api

In the process of making a Firefox-extension, I'm testing out the Google Maps [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/overview).
Using the API I would like to make client-side requests to find directions between addresses from the extension.

I'm quite new to JavaScript, but as I understand, I should use the `fetch` function to make http-requests.
I'm making a test request with the following URL: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?key=<my_api_key>&origin=Ca%C3%B1on+City%2C+Colorado&destination=Royal+Gorge+Bridge+%26+Park%2C+Colorado`

The URL works in my browser, and gives the JSON I'm expecting.
However, when I'm trying to use JavaScript to make the request, I get errors.
This is approximately the JS I'm using:

```js
const listing_address = "Cañon City, Colorado"
const goal_address = "Royal Gorge Bridge & Park, Colorado"
const google_maps_base_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?"

let query_data = new URLSearchParams({
    key: api_key,
    origin: listing_address,
    destination: goal_address,
})

let query_url = google_maps_base_url + query_data.toString()
console.debug(query_url)

fetch(query_url)
    .then(data => { return data })
    .then(res => { console.log(res) })
```

I'm running this from a test html file I'm simply opening in my Firefox browser.
This is giving me an error related to "Same Origin Policy" and CORS-headers.
I've googled around and attempted the `no-cors` mode, which gives me an "opaque" response which I'm not able to use.
I've also attempted to add the following headers:

```js
let headers = new Headers()
headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")

fetch(query_url, {
    headers: headers
})
    .then(data => { return data })
    .then(res => { console.log(res) })
```

That results in the same error as earlier, with the CORS-headers missing.

My main questions are:

1. What am I doing wrong so that I can't use the API?
2. Is there a general guide on how to use this API from a client? Hopefully with JS examples - I've googled for several days without finding the simple things I'm looking for.

Hope someone will be able to help.
Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of [CORS request is not working on google directions API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42024771/cors-request-is-not-working-on-google-directions-api)

Answer (score -1):

You must use maps/directions api instead of fetch. Check out documentation and the Google.maps.directionsservice.

[Good answer for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42027164/3163418)

Comment: This looks relevant, but is it possible to do this without having a map object? I don't need the visuals at all, only the directions API.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

directionsService
    .route({
      origin: {
        query: "California",
      },
      destination: {
        query: "Idaho"
      },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((e) => window.alert("Directions request failed due to " + e));
```

From https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple