# Unexpected JSON from GoogleAPIs call?

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework, jsonp

I am working on an Ionic (v1) app, I am doing a simple call to this endpoint:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=25.6909532,-100.3705846&destination=25.6909532,-100.3705846&waypoints=optimize:true|25.6507548,-100.3424051|25.6546534,-100.356101|25.63622,-100.3124573

Which works correctly if you simply open it on a browser, it returns well formed JSON (I can copy it and parse it on a jsonviewer).

But if I call it using $http's jsonp method (I use jsonp because otherwise it will cause a CORS error), it will cause this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

This is my code (simplified):

```
$http.jsonp('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=25.6909532,-100.3705846&destination=25.6909532,-100.3705846&waypoints=optimize:true|25.6507548,-100.3424051|25.6546534,-100.356101|25.63622,-100.3124573', {jsonpCallbackParam: 'callback'})
.then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

Also I see that the browser is getting the json response correctly:
[image]

Comment: jsonp expects a json structure wrapped in an function:
JSON_CALLBACK ({ /* JSON */ })
Your url returns just a plain json object.

Comment: Thanks, that's going to be the problem. The thing is that if I don't use jsonp, it gives me a CORS related error when I call.

Comment: Yes, I think you have to use google's javascript library:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29834185/how-do-i-get-json-from-google-directions-api-using-jquery